I have an error while extracting details from a website and saving to a excel file
I  am getting an error like
Collect Flight Information :: Go to Wego, select direct flight, an... .
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52559/devtools/browser/9d60cf4c-5e22-4151-ad42-6068832c599b
..[20048:20564:0725/115834.769:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for ec2-52-23-111-175.compute-1.amazonaws.com., errorcode: -105
....Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#141 is a dynamic-sized tensor).
Collect Flight Information :: Go to Wego, select direct flight, an... | FAIL |
Element 'xpath=(//div[@class='flights-results-list']//a[contains(@href, 'flight')])[1]' not visible after 1 minute.
